# Use controls that are created at runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, events, runtime, controls

I am creating a textbox and a checkbox at runtime:

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Name = "txtPassword";
tb.PasswordChar = '*';

CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
cb.Text = "Show Password";
cb.Name = "cbShowPassword";
cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cbShowPassword_CheckedChanged);
```

And I want to mask or unmask the password according to the checkbox:

```
private void cbShowPassword_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtPassword.PasswordChar = cbShowPassword.Checked ? '\0' : '*';
}
```

The problem is, it doesn't recognize **txtPassword** and **cbShowPassword** under **cbShowPassword_CheckedChanged**, since it is created in the code.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, you use a local variable `tb` in the method in which you instantiate the control. You can use that variable only in the method that instantiates the control. The fact that you gave the control a name does not mean that there is a variable defined named `txtPassword`.

You could continue this way, and dynamically look the control up from any other methods that wish to refer to it. However, that makes life harder than it needs to be. What you really want is a variable that refers to the control.

So, create a private member field of your class named `txtPassword`. Create the control like this:

```
txtPassword = new TextBox();
txtPassword.PasswordChar = '*';
....
```

To be really clear, `txtPassword` is a private member of your class, not a local variable.

Then you will be able to refer to it from other methods. Is there is a possibility that it might not have been created, test `txtPassword` against `null`.

Obviously you use the same technique for any other dynamically created controls.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing something up.

Did you add the controls to the parent form/controls?
Does the event fire ? (put a break point in there)
Try to use them as members instead of the name property and access this.cb and this.tb

Answer (score 0):

You could use your form to find any Child controls that matches your newly created textboxes and Checkboxes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx

Else you could set a reference to this objects in a property on the Form.